# Como saco la serie fibonacci usando recursividad anidada en java

Tags: java, fibonacci

Necesito convertir este código para que use recursividad anidada pero cuando lo intento me da otro resultado o se cae

```
 public int fibonacci(int n){
    if (n == 0 || n == 1)
    return n;
    else
    return fibonacci(n-1)+fibonacci(n-2);
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aqui hay un ejemplo de fibonacci recursivo:

```
     public static void main(String[] args) {
          int numeroElementos = 9;
          for(int i = 0; i < numeroElementos; i++){
               System.out.print(funcionFibonacci(i) + ", ");
          }
     }

     private static int funcionFibonacci(int num){
          if(num == 0 || num==1)
               return num;
          else
               return funcionFibonacci(num-1) + funcionFibonacci(num-2);
     }
```

El resultado es el siguiente:

```
0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21,
```

La respuesta fue tomada de [Fibonacci Recursivo](https://masqueprogramar.wordpress.com/2017/01/18/fibonacci-recursivo/)

Answer (score 2):

Podrías obtener el resultado que deseas preguntando que cantidad de números de la serie que se desean, y posteriormente validar si la cantidad es 1 0 2, ya que dichos números de la serie pueden ser agregados sin mucha lógica con condicionales, y en caso tal de que la cantidad deseada sea superior entonces usarías un método recursivo para ir agregando elemento en un arreglo.

```java
public class Fibonacci {

    public static int[] Fibonacci(int cantidad) {
        int[] serie = new int[cantidad];

        if (cantidad > 0) serie[0] = 0;
        if (cantidad > 1) serie[1] = 1;
        if (cantidad > 2) return Fibonacci(cantidad, 2, serie);
        return serie;
    }

    public static int[] Fibonacci(int cantidad, int indice, int[] serie) {
        serie[indice] = serie[indice - 2] + serie[indice - 1];
        indice++;
        if (indice < cantidad) {
            return Fibonacci(cantidad, indice, serie);
        }
        return serie;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] serieFibonacci = Fibonacci(5);
    }
}
```