# Fibonacci Recursivo

Tags: java, bucle-for, recursión, fibonacci

Tengo la siguiente duda: ¿Cómo implemento la sucesión de Fibbonacci de manera recursiva para un número que yo le pase por parametro?
Yo tengo el siguiente for, que me calcula la sucesión de Fibbonacci para los 10 primeros números:

```
int i = 0, a = 0, b = 1, c = 0;
        
System.out.println(" ");
System.out.println("Fibbonacci con estructura for: ");

for (i = 0; i < 10; i++){          
    if (i < 9){
        System.out.print(a + ","); 
        c = a + b; 
        a = b; 
        b = c; 
    } 
    else{
        System.out.println(a); 
    }
}
```

Mi duda consiste en como podría hacer esta sucesión de manera recursiva y además del número que el usuario pase por teclado. Tengo lo siguiente de momento:

```
public class recursivo {
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        int n;
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Calcular fibonacci");
        System.out.println("Introduce el numero del que deseas hacer fibonacci");
        n = teclado.nextInt();
    }
    public static int Fibonacci(int sol, int n) {
        if (n == 1 || n==2) {
            sol = 1;
        } else {
            
        }
        return sol;
    }
}
```

Muchas gracias de antemano, un saludo.

Comment: Dentro del for, en la parte `i < 10` el 10 se lo agregas como valor asignado

Comment: Si, eso valdría. Pero me gustaría que fuera de manera recursiva y con varias clases

Comment: Cierto, terminaste de editar eso cuando comente. No me queda claro que quieres que sea recursivo, si el fibonacci, o que cuando acabe, puedas volver a empezar otra vez, en ese caso, luego de mostrar resultado, llamarías nuevamente a un promt y al metodo.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Como saco la serie fibonacci usando recursividad anidada en java](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/251110/como-saco-la-serie-fibonacci-usando-recursividad-anidada-en-java)

Comment: Entiendo que es una tarea y te piden expresamente que sea recursivo, porque en realidad la opción recursiva para sacar fibbonacci es muy muy muy mala.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu primer algoritmo usa la técnica de **programación dinámica**, la cual es mucho más eficiente en tiempo de ejecución que la técnica de **programación recursiva**, la cual tiene un tiempo de ejecución mucho más lento y en este caso específico tiene varios inconvenientes ya que si usamos esta técnica recursiva, se creará un árbol de llamadas que tendra funciones con los mismos parámetros n-veces , o dicho de otra forma se calcula lo mismo varias veces, un ejemplo supongamos que vamos a calcular la **función Fibonacci** para **n = 5**; recursivamente sería la suma de todos los **Fibonacci** que preceden al **fib(5)** algo así como **F = fib(5) + fib(4) + fib(3) + fib(2) + fib(1) + fib(0)**, si aplicamos la **función F = fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)**, y nos vamos por la llamada a la primera función fib(antes del operador +)

**F(5) = fib(4) + fib(3)**, si seguimos igualmente por la rama izquierda tendríamos
**F(4) = fib(3) + fib(2)** , fíjate que todo eso es por la rama izquierda, cuando entremos a la rama derecha de la función estaríamos calculando fibonnaccis que ya previamente hemos calculado lo cual es ineficiente, después de toda esta explicación te recomiendo que uses la técnica de **programación dinámica** y que busques más información en internet sobre esto.

Recursivamente se hace así, que es en realidad lo que estás preguntando:

```
private static int Fibonacci(int num)
{
    if(num == 0 || num == 1)
    {
        return num;
    }
    else
    {
        return Fibonacci(num-1) + Fibonacci(num-2);
    }
 }
```